# Typescript Union Array using String Enum for Key Names

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to short form this statement:

```
Array<{ [enum.example1]: Example } | { [enum.example2]: Example } | ...>
// or equivalent
({ [enum.example1]: Example } | { [enum.example2]: Example } | ...)[];
```

So it is more succinct like `{ [key: string]: Example }`, but uses a string enum to restrict the possible keys:

For example, these don't appear to work:

```
{ [enum]: Example }[];
// or
{ [key: enum]: Example }[];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same [syntax](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html) as for a limited set of string literals:

```
{ [key in MyEnum]?: Example }[]
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tnqosb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for a demo.

Comment: Is it possible do something similar with an interface like in this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gmq9qp?embed=1&file=src/app/example.model.ts?  Seems to indicate an error, and if I change the keys in `test` to something outside the enum it seems to accept it.

Comment: According to the error message, it appears to be disallowed in an interface declaration. I don't know if there is a workaround in that case.

Comment: Thanks, you're right.  Looks like it isn't.  You need to use an alias like `export type Alias = { [key in Example]: string; }`, or wait for https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26797.